# Vuex store this.$store is undefined in Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a new vue-cli webpack project using Vuex. I've initialized my Vuex store in store.js like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {}
});

export default store;
```

In my App.vue I am importing store from `'./store.js'` which works just fine, but `this.$store` is undefined. What am I missing?

Here is my App.vue

```
<script>
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation";
import axios from "axios";
import store from "./store";
export default {
  created() {
    console.log("store from $store", this.$store);
    console.log("store from store: ", store);
  }
}
</script>
```

The second `console.log(store)` works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. In my main.js I was not setting the store on the Vue instance. For anyone else that ever gets stuck on this, here's what you need:
`main.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store"; // this
require("./assets/styles/main.scss");

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store, // and this
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

Comment: well, the documentation tells you exactly this....   https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html